# VMWare. Под виртуальную машину Mac OS выделяется 3MB графической памяти

Tags: macos, vmware

Доброго времени суток! Возникла необходимость работать в XCode со Swift 3. MacBook'a у меня нет, поэтому для этого поставил приложение VMWare WorkStation и установил образ Mac OS 10.11. Она запускается и исправно работает, но до жути медленно. Вероятнее всего, это связано с маленьким объемом памяти (3 MB) графического устройства. Скриншоты сведений о системе и видеоадаптере прилагаются.
Вопрос заключается в следующем: Существуют ли какие-либо пути решения данной проблемы?

Также стоит упомянуть, что в настройках Display виртуальной машины возле CheckBox (Accelerate 3D Graphics) есть Warning: 3D acceleration is not supported in this guest operating system. Graphics memory выделяется по умолчанию 256 MB

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неожиданно было найдено решение данной проблемы. Странно, но в русско- и англоязычном интернете ответа я так и не нашел. Оно заключается в следующем:

1. Открываем VMWare WorkStation;
2. Запускаем виртуальную машину (в нашем случае, это Mac OS)
3. В панели меню VMWare WorkStation выбираем VM/Install VMWare Tools..

После установки все будет работать как надо. Видеопамяти для виртуальной машины стало выделяться 128 MB.

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы вместо 128 MB памяти было больше?